How to calculate $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{nx^n}{1+x^n}$?
I have an unprecise method
$$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{nx^n}{1+x^n}=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{t^\frac{1}{n}}{1+t}=\int_{0}^{1}\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^kx^{k+\frac{1}{n}}=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{1}(-1)^kx^{k+\frac{1}{n}}=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^k\frac{1}{\frac{1}{n}+k+1}$$
$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^k\frac{1}{\frac{1}{n}+k+1}=ln2$$
However,$\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^kx^{k+\frac{1}{n}}$ isn't uniform convergence when $x\in(0,1)$. So, my answer is wrong.
Then, how can I solve this question?

Do you know the dominated convergence theorem?

Did you miss a dx (or two) somewhere in writing your question?

@CrimsonDark I think, It is modern approach to integrals.

You may integrate by parts:
$$\int_0^1x\frac{nx^{n-1}}{1+x^n}\, dx= \left.x\ln(1+x^n)\right|_0^1-\underbrace{\int_0^1\ln(1+x^n)\, dx}_{=:I_n}= \ln 2 - I_n$$
Now, you can use the dominated convergence theorem on $I_n$.
Or you show using $\int_0^t\frac 1{1+t}\,dt = \ln(1+t)$ that
$$\frac {x^n}2 \leq \ln(1+x^n)\leq x^n \text{ for } 0\leq x \leq 1$$
Squeezing then shows that $\displaystyle I_n \stackrel{n\to \infty}{\rightarrow} 0$.

You can also use DCT directly on the integral $\int_0^1{\frac{t^{1/n}}{1+t},dt}$.

How about substitution $z=1+x^n$? Then $\frac{dz}{dx}=nx^{n-1}$, $x=\sqrt[n]{z-1}$, $z(0)=1$, $z(1)=2$, i.e.
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^1\frac{nx^n}{1+x^n}dx=\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_1^2\sqrt[n]{z-1}\,\frac{dz}z$$
Then note, that within this realm the only $n$-depending component $\sqrt[n]{z-1}$ surely tends to 1, thus you are left with
$$\int_1^2\frac{dz}z=\ln(2)-\ln(1)=\ln(2)-0$$

It seems that you are comfortable in your realm.:)

There is no need of convergence theorems nor integration formulas. Elementary methods are sufficient. Moreover we get an explicit estimate of the difference between the $n\rm th$ integral and $\ln 2.$
We have
$$\int\limits_0^1{nx^n\over 1+x^n}\,dx=  \int\limits_0^1{nx^{n-1}\over 1+x^n}\,dx\\ - \int\limits_0^1{nx^{n-1}(1-x)\over 1+x^n}\,dx=\ln 2 -\int\limits_0^1{nx^{n-1}(1-x)\over 1+x^n}\,dx$$ Furthermore
$$ 0\le \int\limits_0^1{nx^{n-1}(1-x)\over 1+x^n}\,dx\le \int\limits_0^1nx^{n-1}(1-x)\,dx \\ = 1-{n\over n+1}={1\over n+1}$$
Summarizing we have obtained $$ \ln 2-{1\over n+1}\le \int\limits_0^1{nx^{n}\over 1+x^n}\,dx\le \ln 2$$
Hence the limit is equal $\ln 2.$

Let us make the substitution $x=e^{-\frac tn}$. Then,
$$I_n=\int_0^1\frac{nx^n}{1+x^n}dx=\int_0^\infty\frac{e^{-\frac tn}}{e^t+1}dt.$$
For all $t\geq0$, we have $$1-\frac tn\leq e^{-\frac tn}\leq 1.$$
Therefore,
$$\eta(1)-\frac{\eta(2)}{n}\leq I_n\leq\eta(1)$$
where $\eta(s)$ is the Dirichlet eta function. Using the well-known special values $\eta(1)=\ln2$ and $\eta(2)=\frac{\pi^2}{12}$ of the D. eta function, we have
$$\ln2-\frac{\pi^2}{12n}\leq I_n\leq\ln2$$
and by Squeeze theorem, $\lim_{n\to\infty} I_n=\ln2$.

Just for your curiosity.
If you use the integral representation of harmonic numbers
$$I_n=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{nx^n}{1+x^n}\,dx=\frac{1}{2} \left(H_{\frac{1}{2 n}}-H_{\frac{1}{2n}-\frac 12}\right)$$ and for large values of $n$
$$I_n=\log (2)-\frac{\pi ^2}{12 n}+\frac{3 \zeta (3)}{4
   n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)$$ which gives the limit, upper and lower bounds and a good estimate (even for non integer values of $n$). The relative error of less than $0.1$% as soon as $n>11$.
